# Known states for testnet on fast sync mode Nov - 2018

Tags: synchronization, fast-sync

Whats the current knownStates for testnet on fast sync mode Nov - 2018

Is there an online service which provides the current states of the ethereum testnet.

It been several days and `--testnet` `fast` sync haven't completed yet:

```
> eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 4488662,
  highestBlock: 4488733,
  knownStates: 60311013,
  pulledStates: 60309733,
  startingBlock: 4474887
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Which testnet are you talking about? there are 3 popular ones.
The easiest fastest way to manually check would be etherscan.
If you want to query an external node by code, I'd use infura's node

Depending on the node you are using, there are RPC calls that will tell you what that node knows, in parity's case:

```
{"method":"parity_chainStatus","params":[],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}
```

But it seems that you have a node configuration problem, check your peers, maybe you are not receiving blocks, or receiving them from a bad source.